# Why am I getting $\pi(n)=\operatorname{li}(n)+O\left(\log^2 n\right)$

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, factorial, fake-proofs

I was trying to see if I could prove the Prime Number Theorem using Legendre's formula. I did it the following way:

We hae

$$\log n!=n(\log n-1)+O(\log n)=\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}\log p=(n-O(\log n))\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{\log p}{p-1}$$

Coming from [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation?useskin=vector) and [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).

Then,

\begin{align}
\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{\log p}{p-1}&=\frac{n}{n-O(\log n)}(\log n-1)+O\left(\frac{\log n}n\right) \\
&= \left(1+O\left(\frac{\log n}n\right)\right)(\log n-1)+O\left(\frac{\log n}n\right) \\
&=\log n-1+O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\right)=f(n)
\end{align}

Which we can then differentiate:

$$\frac{df}{dn}=\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}\right)=\frac{d\pi}{dn}\frac{\log n}{n-1}$$

Because there is a $\frac{d\pi}{dn}$ chance that $n$ is prime and that $\frac{\log n}{n-1}$ will be added to the sum.

Then,

\begin{align}
\frac{d\pi}{dn}&=\frac{n-1}{\log n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\\
\end{align}

And finally with integration, we get

$$\pi(n)=\operatorname{li}(n)+O\left(\log^2 n\right)$$

Which is a *very very very strong* error bound on $\pi(n)-\operatorname{li}(n)$, considering the best known asymptotic (even after assuming RH) is

$$\pi(n)=\operatorname{li}(n)+O(\sqrt n\log n)$$

So where have I gone wrong, and what would this method give me in the end? I suspect it's in the imprecise definition of differentiation but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, my question is why my approximation is so "good" that it can't be true.

Comment: Isn't, in the row with $f(n)$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\log(x)^{2}}{x}\right) 
= \frac{ \frac{2\log(x)}{x} - \log(x)^{2}}{x^{2} } = O\left(\frac{\log(x)^{2}}{x^{2}}\right)$$ so that in the end you have $$\frac{d\pi}{dn} = \frac{1}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{1}{\log(n)}\right)$$

Comment: Also, in general, big-O cannot be differentiated.

Comment: @Manifoldski Actually, I did initially get that, but when I sat down to type I decided to run it through Derivative Calculator but put in $\frac{\log n}{n}$. Oops.

Comment: Also, as @Gary points out, you need some justification for differentiating big oh. For instance bounded functions $O(1)$ don't necessarily have zero derivatives.

Comment: Yep, but what if it was the average derivative over an interval? What I was thinking was that it would be possible maybe to consider $f\left(\left(1+\Delta n\right)n\right)-f(n)$ for some $\Delta n\ll1$.

Comment: @Kyky I am not sure. I hope someone more knowledgeable can come along to give more comprehensive commentary on your, in my opinion, interesting attempt!

Comment: One cannot differentiate big-O terms directly. An example would be $\sin(e^x)=O(1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first equation seems to be using an estimate $s_p(n) = O(\log n)$, where $s_p(n)$ is the number of digits in the base-$p$ expansion of $n$. However, $n$ has $\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log p} \rfloor + 1$ digits in base $p$, and each digit can be as large as $p-1$; therefore the best estimate one can get for $s_p(n)$ is around $\frac p{\log p} \log n$. And since $p$ can be close to $n$, the $\frac p{\log p}$ term is huge....

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that
$$\log n!=(n-O(\log n))\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{\log p}{p-1}$$